# very low performance in apache server (windows 2012 R2)

Tags: performance, apache-2.4, memory-usage

I have a brand new HP server with windows 2012 r2 64 bits. It has 2 Xeon Processors E-5 2603 v3. (1.6ghz) and 32 GB ram and runs XAMPP (apache 2.4, mysql 5.7, php 5.6). The server is not yet in production..

The program has some big scripts (like generating large pdf files of patients clinical histories, over 450 pages).

My personal computer is a standard pc, with an Intel core i3 (3.2 ghz) processor, 4GB ram, Windows 10 64 bit.

How is it possible that my personal computer has much better performance than the new server? The large scripts that take about 40 seconds on my computer, take up to 3 minutes on the new server, running the same versions of apache, mysql, php and exactly the same settings.

While the script is running, I open the task manager, and I see that the new server only uses 9% of its cpu. It uses only one of its 12 cores. Also the usage of memory is very low.

I suspect the difference is made by the hyper threading of the i3 processor over the xeon. it's possible?

Is there a way to make better use of resources? I know that the new server hardware is working properly because it has been reviewed by HP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question: On your local PC, you have a single thread at 3.2Ghz. On your server, you have a single thread a 1.6Ghz. Now, your Xeon processor can do more instructions per cycle, and has a much larger L2 cache. But all that is meaningless unless your software takes advantage of it.

When you are working with a single-threaded script like you describe, then you need fewer, faster cores. Not more smaller cores.

To make this script scale better, you will probably have to thread the PDF generation process. Without knowing anything about the kinds of documents you are producing, I would suggest breaking apart the generation into sections, and running each section in parallel. Once you have all of your sections generated, glue your resulting PDFs together.

If you *can't* do this for whatever reason, then there may not be much you can do. You need to purchase hardware that is suited for your situation, and in this case you have a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp is not for production servers. Not meant for security. Good for testing/developing through.
Instead of that install on your 'brand new hp server' hyperv role, then debian & apache and then compare performance of the script.

Comment: What makes you think it will be in any way different, just by changing operating systems?

Comment: its called experience ;) - also this: PHP BENCHMARK SCRIPT - Xampp 9.723 | Linux (Debian): 6.098s - the same virtual machines specs (2 cores, 4 gb ram, ssd); although it not explains 'very low' performance - I suspect configuration errors in host machine.